# Jquery post not changing value on response

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have some jquery that runs when a link is clicked (below).  This allows data to be sent to a mysql database and then update the value of a certain `<p>`.  However, this isn't working.  I added an `alert(response)` and i am getting the correct result, but the `<p>` doesnt change which probably means i am using the wrong selector.

JQUERY:

```
$('.upVote').click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

        answer_id = $(this).siblings('.record_id').attr('value');

        $.post('../answerrating.php' , {answer_id: answer_id} , function(response){

            $(this).prev('.ratingBox').val(response);
        });

});
```

HTML:

```
<p class='ratingBox'> $answerrating[$f]</p>
                     <a href='#' class='upVote'>Upvote</a> <a href='#' class='downVote'>Downvote</a>
                    <input type='hidden' name='record_id' value='$answerid[$f]' class='record_id' />
```

Comment: what is response ?? html ????

Comment: @dku.rajkumar response is a number that is echoed from php like '25'.  i would like this number to be inside .ratingBox

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to access the $(this) inside ajax success callback function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643798/how-to-access-the-this-inside-ajax-success-callback-function)

Comment: try my answer... hope it would work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this.

```
$('.upVote').click(function(e){    
    e.preventDefault();    
    var target_elem = $(this).prev('.ratingBox');
        answer_id = $(this).siblings('.record_id').attr('value');    
        $.post('../answerrating.php' , {answer_id: answer_id} , function(response){    
            target_elem.text(response);
        });    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`this` will not refer to the element that was clicked inside of your AJAX callback. Try storing the context of the event handler and using it in your callback function instead.

Additionally, you should use [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text) or [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html) when modifying the contents of non-`input` elements:

```
$('.upVote').click(function(e){
    var self = this;

    e.preventDefault();

        var answer_id = $(this).siblings('.record_id').attr('value');

        $.post('../answerrating.php' , {answer_id: answer_id} , function(response){

            $(self).prev('.ratingBox').html(response);
        });

});
```

Comment: @user802370: What does response look like? Is it what you expect?

Comment: @user802370: Oops! Just noticed another problem -- make sure to use `.text()` or `.html()` instead of `val` for `p` tags.

Answer (score 0):

The error is likely because the value of the special variable `this` inside the `.post()`s success callback is almost certainly not the DOM element that the click event handler was responding to.

To solve this, set a variable for the value of `this` in the click callback, and refer to it inside the success callback. This is a good practise in general, wherever you aren't 100% sure what the value of `this` will be, as it varies significantly by context.

```
$('.upVote').click(function(e){
    var button = this;
    e.preventDefault();    
    answer_id = $(this).siblings('.record_id').attr('value');

    $.post('../answerrating.php' , {answer_id: answer_id} , function(response){
        $(button).prev('.ratingBox').val(response);
    });
});
```

Comment: It is probably also helpful to change the answer_id line to be `var answer_id = $(button)...` as well, making sure to use the `var` keyword to avoid creating a global variable.