# In jQuery, how can I access $(this) from an $.ajax callback function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to access the $(this) inside ajax success callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643798/how-to-access-the-this-inside-ajax-success-callback-function)

I have a code like this:

```
$('.each_button').click(function(){

$.ajax({ type: 'POST', url: process.php, data: data, success: function(data){

/////
       }
   })
});
```

How can I access the very `$('.each_button')` that triggered the event? I tried `$(this)` but it doesn't work, probably because it's inside of another function..

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: argh.. didn't see it in the suggestions.. I can't close it, now that someone has answered

Comment: just flagged myself. Thanks for letting me know. Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everyone wants to use a variable for some reason. This isn't necessary.

```
$('.each_button').click(function(){

    $.ajax({
        context: this, // <-- do this instead...
        type: 'POST', 
        url: process.php, 
        data: data, 
        success: function(data) {
               // ...now 'this' is the element you want
            alert(this.className);
        }
    });

});
```

---

Or use `$.proxy` if you prefer...

```
$('.each_button').click(function(){

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST', 
        url: process.php, 
        data: data, 
        success: $.proxy(function(data) {
               // ...now 'this' is the element you want
            alert(this.className);
        }, this) // <-- bind the context
    });

});
```

---

One benefit to these approaches is that it lets you reuse the `success` function...

```
function ajax_success(data) {
    alert(this.className);
}

$('.each_button').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        context: this,
        type: 'POST', 
        url: process.php, 
        data: data, 
        success: ajax_success
    });
});
```

Comment: The first example was neat! I was not aware of the functionality! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You could save the object in another variable and access it inside the `function(data)`.

Something like this:

```
$('.each_button').click(function(){
    var $obj = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST', 
        url: process.php, 
        data: data, 
        success: function(data) {
            $obj.val(data.foobar);
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Oh, without using `var`? Not a nice idea.

Comment: @bažmegakapa: vups, forgot that. Thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 1):

Catch this in a variable before the ajax call:

```
$('.each_button').click(function(){

    var $this = $(this);

    $.ajax({ type: 'POST', url: process.php, data: data, success: function(data){

            alert($this);

       }
   })
});
```