# How to set content of <a> from JQuery Ajax response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to access the $(this) inside ajax success callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643798/how-to-access-the-this-inside-ajax-success-callback-function)

I can't understand why this doesn't work:

```
    $("body").on("click", "a.linky", function () {
        var contentID = $(this).attr("contentID");

        var jsongo = 'id=' + contentID;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Controller/Action/',
            data: jsongo,
            success: function (msg) {
                $(this).html(msg);
                alert(msg);

            }
        });

    });
```

I am able to display the alert, but I can't set the html for the clicked link... Is there any way I can find the properties and methods from Elements from JQuery point of view? I find very confusing the reference from Jquery documentation.

What should be the correct way to set the content of the Link from the code above?

thanks

Comment: Is `this` referring to `a.linky` or `window`?

Comment: Are you sure? You should `console.log(this);` in `success` and check; I think it's probably a `jqXHR` and not a jQuery/DOM node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing it this way

```
    $("body").on("click", "a.linky", function () {
        $this = $(this);
        var contentID = $(this).attr("contentID");
```

and then inside your ajax

```
  $this.html(msg);
```

to reference the right element

## EDIT:

As explained more in the comments, it is happening because `this` inside the ajax call is not referencing back the element that triggered the event but rather the ajax settings. Please see the [ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

> The this reference within all callbacks is the object in the context option passed to $.ajax in the settings; if context is not specified, this is a reference to the Ajax settings themselves.

Comment: See, that's what I'm thinking. See the console here: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/MCRF9/1/

Comment: it worked great, but I can't figure why $(this).html(msg) wouldn't work

Comment: @Edwin: From the documentation: *"The `this` reference within all callbacks is the object in the `context` option passed to `$.ajax` in the settings; if `context` is not specified, `this` is a reference to the Ajax settings themselves."* (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). As you see, `this` is not a reference to the DOM element.

Comment: @EdwinSoho - It's because it's called at a later time with a different scope, so `this` is not the same as `this` in the event handler.