# Jquery each table - hide show using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

My application is MVC 5, I am trying to using the following script to hide and show a button in each row based on the value I get from database using Ajax.

```
function setButtons() {
        $('#MyList > tbody  > tr').each(function () {
         var typeid  =  $(this).find("select").val();
         if (typeid != null ) {
          $.ajax({
                url: '/MyController/GetInfo',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    id: typeid
                }
            })
            .success(function (data) {
                var tr;
                if (data == null) {
                    $(this).find("button#Details0").hide();
                } else {
                    $(this).find("button#Details0").show();
                }
            })
        .error(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
            alert("error");
        });
        }
        });
```

I have tested Ajax by itself, it works, I get the value from select, and receive data back from the controller.  I suspect the problem could be in using "this" inside the Ajax script.  Would appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the `$(this)` to a variable so in can be used in the success function

```
function setButtons() {
  $('#MyList > tbody  > tr').each(function () {
    var self = $(this); // store the value
    var typeid  =  $(this).find("select").val();
    if (typeid != null ) {
      $.ajax({
        url: '/MyController/GetInfo', // recommend '@Url.Action("GetInfo", "MyController")'
        type: 'POST',
        data: { id: typeid }
      })
      .success(function (data) {
        var tr; // ? not used
        if (data == null) {
          self.find("button#Details0").hide(); // change this
        } else {
          self.find("button#Details0").show(); // and this
        }
      })
      .error(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
        alert("error");
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Note also `jqXHR.success()` and `jqXHR.error()` have been deprecated. Use `.done` and `.fail` instead

Comment: Thank you so much Stephen, the trick is in setting the variable to $(this).  I tried before without $().  Great help, it works.

Comment: Side note: `self.find("button#Details0").hide()` suggest you have a button in each table row with `id="Details0"` which is invalid html. Suggest you use a class name for the button instead to avoid duplicate ID's

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function setButtons() {
    $('#MyList > tbody  > tr').each(function () {
     var typeid  =  $(this).find("select").val();
     var that = this
     if (typeid != null ) {
      $.ajax({
            url: '/MyController/GetInfo',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                id: typeid
            }
        })
        .success(function (data) {
            var tr;
            if (data == null) {
                $(that).find("button#Details0").hide();
            } else {
                $(that).find("button#Details0").show();
            }
        })
    .error(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
        alert("error");
    });
    }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you, please check Stephen answer. Setting the variable that should equal to $(this).

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery ajax method, you can add a property called *context*. Clean and easy.

```
....
$.ajax({
  url: '/MyController/GetInfo',
  type: 'POST',
  context: this, <---- add this
  data: {
      id: typeid
  }
})
....
```

Related: [how to access the $(this) inside ajax success callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643798/how-to-access-the-this-inside-ajax-success-callback-function)