# $(this) with .class selector in JQuery UI Autocomplete Widget

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

```
        <!--html-->
        <tr>
          <td data-id="54">
            <input type="text" class="suggestexam" />
          </td>
        <tr>
        <tr>
          <td data-id="16">
            <input type="text" class="suggestexam" />
          </td>
        <tr>
        //JQuery
        $(".suggestexam").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "/Employee/GetExamNameSuggestion",
                data: "{'prefix':'" + request.term + "','testval':'"+ $(this).closest('td').attr('data-id') +"'}",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    response(data.d);
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

But `$(this).closest('td').attr('data-id')` returns undefined.

Any help?

Comment: `$(this).closest('td').data('id') ` try

Comment: @guradio, it's not working also.

Comment: did you try the snippet in the answer?

Comment: @guradio, No. My problem is little different than your answer.

Comment: `But $(this).closest('td').attr('data-id') returns undefined.`? i dont really understand enlighten me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div data-id="54">
    <input type="text" name="tag" class="autosuggest" id="tagid" />
</div>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('body').on('focus', ".autosuggest", function () {
                var autosuggestType = $(this).closest('div').attr("data-id");
                $(this).autocomplete({
                    source: function (request, response) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "/Home/FetchTagList",
                            data: JSON.stringify({ tag: request.term, exid: autosuggestType }),
                            dataType: "json",
                            type: "POST",
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
                            success: function (data) {
                                console.log(data.data);
                                response($.map(data.data, function (item) {
                                    return {
                                        value: item.TagName
                                    }
                                }))
                            },
                            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                alert(textStatus);
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    minLength: 1
                });
            });
            //$(".autosuggest").each(function (index, object) { });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643798/how-to-access-the-this-inside-ajax-success-callback-function).Try this:

```
//JQuery
 var dataId = $(".suggestexam").closest('td').attr('data-id');
 $(".suggestexam").autocomplete({
     source: function(request, response) {
         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             url: "/Employee/GetExamNameSuggestion",
             data: "{'prefix':'" + request.term + "','testval':'" + dataId + "'}",
             dataType: "json",
             success: function(data) {
                 response(data.d);
             },
             error: function(result) {
                 alert("Error");
             }
         });
     }
 });
```

Comment: I have multiple .suggestexam.

Comment: @s.k.paul When do you wnat to get `data-id` ?

Comment: @s.k.paul Can you post your completed code or provide a demo?

Comment: I hope this snippet is enough to get the idea.

Comment: @s.k.paul Do you want to send an `ajax request` for each `.suggestexam`?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('input').focus(function() {

  console.log($(this).parent().closest('td').data('id'))
  
  $(this).val($(this).parent().closest('td').data('id'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td data-id="54">
      <input type="text" class="suggestexam" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Try this