# django-ajax-uploader: get the clicked element on upload success

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, file, upload

I am using django-ajax-uploader to upload files with Ajax:
https://github.com/skoczen/django-ajax-uploader.

I would like to get the clicked element once the upload has succeeded.
Here is the code:

```
$('.file-uploader').each(function()
{
    input_element=$(this);

    var uploader = new qq.FileUploader(
    {
        action: "{% url 'campaigns:my_ajax_upload' %}" ,
        element: input_element[0],
        multiple: false,
        onComplete: function(id, fileName, responseJSON) 
        {
            ...
        },
        onAllComplete: function(uploads) 
        {
            ...
            //how to get the element that triggered the upload?
        },
    });
});
```

The problem here is that there are many `file-uploader` elements in the same page, so if I use `input_element` to get the clicked button that triggered the upload, I will only get the button that was last loaded!

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the answer, you can `bind` the `onAllComplete` so you can use `this` inside the `callback` method:

```
onAllComplete: function(uploads) 
{
       window.console&&console.log("All complete!");
       //this is accessible and binded to the right object
       $(this).closest(".show_hide") ... ;
}.bind(this),
```

I have found the answer in an other SO post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30797378/1875861