# How to select current element by class inside in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a loop that dynamically populates information.

```
<div class="main">

 <div class="more">
    more
 </div>
 <span></span>
   ....
 <div class="more">
    more
 </div>
 <span></span>

</div>
```

on clicking specific div I am calling "ajax" - on success I want to override that specific div's content and next span with some content.

```
   $(document).on("click", ".more", function (event) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '..',
                datatype: 'application/json',
                success: function (data) {
                    $(".more",this).html("Update Dev"); //update div
                    $(".more",this).find('span:first').text("Update Span"); //update span 
                },
                error: function () { alert('something bad happened'); }
            });
        });
```

How would I access the element that was clicked.

Thanks

Comment: $(this) is what you need.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643798/how-to-access-the-this-inside-ajax-success-callback-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$(this)` inside click handler to get the clicked button. Make sure to capture it in click handler, not in AJAX callback:

```
$(document).on("click", ".more", function (event) {
    var clickedDiv = $(this);  // <- capture clicked div to variable

    $.ajax({
        url: '..',
        datatype: 'application/json',
        success: function (data) {
            // use captured div to set the contents
            clickedDiv.html("Update Dev");
            // use captured div and function next() to get the span element
            clickedDiv.next('span').html("Updated span");  // then update span
        },
        error: function () { alert('something bad happened'); }
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks so much for the explanation. The span would not update. I modified by ` clickedDiv.next('span').html("Updated span");` and it worked.

Comment: @Ben Yes, you are right - I copied selector from the div and I did not notice that `span` does not have `more` class. I updated the answer

Comment: I was wondering is it easy to add .animate for example when div is changing? I know I didn't specify in my question, is it something simple to add?