# removing users from page on button click using ajax technology

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to remove the whole element on button click.
Removal must be done through Ajax technology, that is, without reloading the page.
After deleting a user, the entry with him should disappear from the list of all users.

**Here is the structure of my code:**

```
<?php
    require_once "lib/mysql.php"; //database connection
    $query = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM `users`');
    $query->execute();
    $users = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach($users as $user) {
        echo '<div class="infoAllUsers"><b>Name: </b>' . $user['name'] . ', <b>Login: </b>' . $user['login'] . '<button onclick="deleteUser('.$user['id'].');">Delete</button></div>';
    }; //display all users

?>

<script>
    function deleteUser(id) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax/deleteUser.php',
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            data: {'id': id},
            success: function(data) {
                $(this).closest(".infoAllUsers").remove();
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

There are no errors in js and php, there is nothing in the console, deletion from the database occurs correctly.
I am new to jQuery so I have tried some things like:

```
$(this).parent('div').remove();
```

```
$(this).closest('div').remove();
```

```
$(this).parent('.infoAllUsers').remove();
```

Comment: Inside the success function, `$(this)` isn't what you expected - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643798/how-to-access-the-this-inside-ajax-success-callback-function

Comment: If `ajax/deleteUser.php` works as expected and deletes the user than this is just a JS/jQuery question. PHP isn't an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    require_once "lib/mysql.php"; //database connection
    $query = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM `users`');
    $query->execute();
    $users = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach($users as $user) {
        echo '<div class="infoAllUsers"><b>Name: </b>' . $user['name'] . ', <b>Login: </b>' . $user['login'] . '<button onclick="deleteUser('.$user['id'].', this);">Delete</button></div>';
    }; //display all users

?>

<script>
    function deleteUser(id, this2) {
        var $t = $(this2);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax/deleteUser.php',
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            data: {'id': id},
            success: function(data) {
                $t.closest('.infoAllUsers').remove();
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code seems correct, the only thing that occurs to me is that your php backend is not returning an Http code that is in the 2XX range and that is why it does not enter the success function of your ajax request, have you tried to make a `console.log()` inside the function that deletes the `<div>` to see if the JS reaches that point?
[Jquery.ajax() function documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: yes i was checking console.log() inside the function and yes it reaches JS to that point

Answer (score 0):

Take a different/cleaner approach

Set the id as a data attribute and assign a class, then add the click event to that.

`<button class="delete" data-id="'.$user['id'].'">Delete</button>`

```
$('.infoAllUsers .delete').click(function(elm) {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'ajax/deleteUser.php',
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    data: {
      'id': $(elm).data('id')
    },
    success: function() {
      $(elm).parent().remove();
    }
  });
})
```

Comment: ERROR: users.php:38 Uncaught TypeError: elm.data is not a function
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (users.php:38:17)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2:41772)
    at y.handle (jquery.min.js:2:39791)

Comment: see edit, not used jq in a while

Comment: now not only the js does not work, but ischo stopped working php)