# How to fill the value and set upon success:function using name object

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I am trying to make autofill, so when user select the item, it will put the value into the input field, but nothing change. I am using the name instead of id.

It work if I do like below.

```
$(document).on('change', '[name="item_media[]"]', function(){
        var itemID = $(this).val();
        var itemType = 1;

            $(this).parents('.body-media').find('[name="value_media[]"]').val(0);
            $(this).parents('.body-media').find('[name="unit_media[]"]').val();
          
    });
```

But What I am trying to do is here, seem on the success:function do not work. When I try to console all the data is there

```
$(document).on('change', '[name="item_media[]"]', function(){
        var itemID = $(this).val();
        var itemType = 1;

        if(itemID){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'?syspath=ajax&controller=ajax&action=getActItemDose',
                data: { 'itemId': itemID, 'itemType': itemType },
                
                
                success:function(data){
                    
                    var object = JSON.parse(data);
                    var value = object.itemValue;
                    var unit = object.itemUnit;
            
                   
                    $(this).parents('.body-media').find('[name="value_media[]"]').val(value);
                    $(this).parents('.body-media').find('[name="unit_media[]"]').val(unit);  
                }
            });

            
        }else{
            $(this).parents('.body-media').find('[name="value_media[]"]').val(0);
            $(this).parents('.body-media').find('[name="unit_media[]"]').val();
           
  
        }
    });
```

This is how I made my html section

```
 <fieldset>
          <div class="input-group body-media">
          <select class="form-select" id="basicSelect" name="item_media[]" required>
          <option value="">Please Select</option>';
                                                        
           foreach($treat as $item_media){
                 $id =  $item_media['media_treat_id'];
                 $name =  $item_media['media_treat_brand'];
                 echo "<option value='$id'>$name</option>";
                 }
                 echo'   
                 </select>
                 <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="value_media[]" placeholder=Input amount use" aria-label="Amount"/>
                 <select class="form-select" id="basicSelect" name="unit_media[]" required>
                 <option value="">Select unit</option>
                 <option value="2">g</option>
                 <option value="3">ml</option>
                 <option value="7">unit</option>
                 </select>
           </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Hi,`$(this)` is not accessible inside success function . So, to use it one way is to store its value in some variable and then use that variable inside success function . Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2643819/10606400) answer